# Serialization of a tuple of memory streams (jagged arrays) using Protobuf.net

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, f#, protobuf-net

Is it possible to serialize a tuple of memory streams created by a binarywriter using Protobuf.net? If I try that, the Protobuf says that it cannot serialize a stream.

What I am after is to serialize a tuple of jagged arrays. I do not want to convert them into 1D arrays because I believe it is not necessary. So I thought that I would serialize the jagged arrays to the memory stream on my own, but I want the Protobuf.net to serialize the tuple for me. I need to have the overall serialization / deserialization as fast as possible.

EDIT:

My overall goal is to send the following jagged array tuple through WCF as fast as possible no matter how. The overall time `from jagged array to jagged array` counts.

```ml
// F# interactive code
#time "on"
#r @"d:\Protobuf\protobuf-net.dll"

let getJaggedArray () =
  let size = 100
  let rnd = System.Random 1
  Array.init size (fun i ->
    Array.init size (fun j ->
      Array.init size (fun k ->
        rnd.NextDouble() )))

let wcfData = (getJaggedArray (), getJaggedArray ()), getJaggedArray ()

let file = new System.IO.FileStream ("test.bin", System.IO.FileMode.Create)
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize (file, wcfData)
file.Close()

// === Future use ===
//[<ServiceContract>]
//type IWCF =
//  
//  [<OperationContract>]
//  [<ProtoBehavior>]
//  abstract Send: wcfData -> unit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuf-net does not current have any specific handling of streams (although it will handle `byte[]`), although I guess it *could* simply consume the `Stream` (serialize) and reproduce a `MemoryStream` (deserialize). If you didn't want to change your model, it should be possible to register a "surrogate" for `Stream` that does exactly that in only a few lines of code (let me know if that is of interest).

It has automatic support for most common "tuple" patterns, but jagged data is again an issue - although again, this *could* be handled if we really needed (more commonly, having an outer- list of objects that themselves *have* an inner-list is a pragmatic workaround to "jagged", and works currently).

If you can post a more complete (ideally runnable) example, I may be able to offer more guidance.

Comment: Well my goal is to send tuple of jagged arrays through WCF as fast as possible. No matter how. I have tried to convert it into 1D array and back but it takes some time which I would like to avoid. So any direct way from jagged array to wire and back is preferable. That is why I was thinking of converting the jagged array directly to stream and back - to make it faster. See my first post.

Comment: @Oldrich it isn't entirely obvious to me where Stream enters into that - my F# is poor, I'm afraid. What is the ultimate shape of the data?

Comment: Right now it does not :). The shape of the data is something like `Tuple<JaggedArray, JaggedArray, Tuple<JaggedArray, int, Double ...>>` I am thinking of what you said. Probably I will get the byte [] from the stream and use it instead. Do you think that it is the best way to get jagged array through the wire?

Comment: @Oldroch I'd need to understand the data fully to comment on "best"; but by the time it is BLOBs all libs like protobuf can do is help you orchestrate it. That might be enough, of course. And it'll most-likely beat DCS. But note that protobuf itself has things like packed array encoding which might be ideal... *if* I can understand the data enough to propose a model for it :p

Comment: I do not know how else to describe my data :). But lets say that this is my data: `Tuple<Double [][][], Double [][][]>`. Is this enough description? I am not good at C# :).

Comment: @Oldrich much easier ;p At the moment, there is no direct support for nested arrays (as the underlying data format doesn't have that), however, it is something I have considered how to support more directly, and I have plans (just not yet written). If you are currently getting the data close to a BLOB, then for now it may be easiest just to pass that BLOB over WCF - it should be reasonable, especially if you can use MTOM.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Hope to see jagged arrays support in the Protobuf.net in the future! :)